# Not able to remove file from a Sharepoint FileCollection list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am working on a function that will check a users file collection in SharePoint for any file that is more than a minute old (this will be changed, and only using it for testing).  However, when the condition is true it goes into removing the file which is older than a minute, but I get the following exception message.

System.InvalidOperationException
The collection was modified. Enumeration operation  may not execute.

```
  private static void check_for_deletion(PHT.OneDrive.Helpers.OneDriveHelper oneDrive, string user)
    {
        FileCollection files = oneDrive.GetOneDriveFilesByFolderName(user);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {

            DateTime creationDate = file.TimeCreated.ToLocalTime();
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan elapsedTime = currentTime.Subtract(creationDate);
            int fileAge = elapsedTime.Minutes;
            int maxTime = 1;


            if (fileAge > maxTime)
            {
                file.DeleteObject();
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to complete it within the same file collection, just loop through it backwards:

```
for (int fileNum = files.Count-1; fileNum >= 0; fileNum--)
    {
        //Assign file within the loop
        var file = files[fileNum];

        DateTime creationDate = file.TimeCreated.ToLocalTime();
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = currentTime.Subtract(creationDate);
        int fileAge = elapsedTime.Minutes;
        int maxTime = 1;


        if (fileAge > maxTime)
        {
            file.DeleteObject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, more elegant than creating a new FileCollection, cant believe I forgot this.

Comment: This just happened to be one of the things I banged my head against years (too many years) ago and for some reason it's one of those solutions that I always remember.

Answer (score 1):

Your modifying the `FileCollection files` inside your `foreach` loop.

Once you complete your search create a new `FileCollection` and copy the contents of `files` to this and then iterate over the new one.